# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when trying to loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Please have a look at this image:

I want to loop through the "TopTens" im my view, We can see that there are 9 objects in
"TopTens", why dooes it say: Object reference not set to an instance of an object?

![enter image description here][1]

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ASP._Page_Views_secure_CreatePageDetailss_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\xxx\xxx\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\Views\Secure\CreatePageDetailss.cshtml:18
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +271
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +120
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +63
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +100
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +131
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +695
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +382
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +431
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +106
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +321
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9514928
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: There are 9 items in that collection but are you sure one of them isn't null? (I'd post few lines of stack trace, with line numbers, too to find such kind of "problems")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one explanation for the code you give us, and that is that one item in your list is `null`.

The statement `@item.LongDesc` will throw a `NullReferenceException` then.

If you allow one of the items in the `TopTens` to be `null`, add a check for null:

```
@if (@item != null)
{
  <p>@item.LongDesc</p>
}
```

Or, if `TopTens` is a `List` just don't add more items then there are, preventing one to be `null`.

Comment: Thank you! I tried adding the if statement inside the foreach...But the breakpoint shows that the code doesnt even get passed the opening foreach-line before throwing an exception. It never even gets to the @item.LongDesc.

Comment: @user2915962: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @user2915962: And what is line 18?

Comment: Im sorry, i dont understand much from the stacktrace...Does line 18 seems to be the problem?

Comment: @user2915962: That is the place the error is thrown.

Comment: oh i get it, line 18 in the view is the loop:
@foreach (var item in Model.TopTenContentPage.TopTens)

Comment: @user2915962: Then either one of the three (Model, TopTenContentPage, TopTens) is `null`. Are you sure you are looking at the last compiled code?

Comment: Yes its the last compiled code, Ok thank you! I´ll look into the three models and see if I can find something thats null. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: SOLVED
I made a silly mistake...At the top of my page i used:
model Models.TopTenContentPage...
I just had to delete the "topcontentpage" from the loop and it worked fine!

Now my @longDesc gets printed on the screen, A quick question though, can I use html.editfor in the loop to be able to edit the strings? Thanks!